# Postgresql setting parameters for query optimization

Tags: database-performance, postgresql-9.5

I am setting **work_mem** and **shared_buffers** parameters of PostgreSQL
 with an increase in values of these parameters, there is no improvement in query 
 performance
 Please let me know what factors need to set to improve query performance?

Comment: Providing and explain analyze output of your query will be useful.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE